# can the HeaderHttpSessionStrategy work with Cookies in Spring Session

Tags: spring-mvc, cookies, spring-session

I am trying to create a simple login page with just sessions and no spring security. I am having issues with spring session and the SPring session with REST documentation is not helpful. My issue is; Is there a way to know if the user has been logged in with HeaderHttpSessionStrategy so that he doesn't need to be redirected to the login page? and if there isn't can i combine HTTPsession headers with cookies?.

Answer (score 1):

after reading this, i finally understood it. [enter link description here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc-boot.html#httpsession-jdbc-boot-running)

do not use HeaderHttpSessionStrategy if you are working with cookies